# Did Teiichi Niiya die at the end of the Dusk Maiden of Amnesia manga?

Tags: dusk-maiden-of-amnesia

I'm sure that he didn't die in the anime, but at the end of the manga, it is implied that Yuuko took him with her to the other realm. (Meaning that he died?)

Answer (score 1):

....just read the epilogue, in case you don't want to...

It's just basically what happened in the anime, Yuuko is back with him and she is now able to go everywhere, France, Italy, the MC house, the MC bathroom, etc...